# Sinatra JSON.parse undefined method when moving helper to another file

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra, helper

I have a route helper that works fine when it's in a "helpers do" block in my route file, but when I move the helper to my helpers.rb file, I get an error. Here is the helper:

```
def processPutRequest(patient_id, request, _class, foreign_key, route_fragment)
  p = Patient.find(patient_id)
  data = request.body.read
  puts 'request body' + data
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  host_with_port = request.host_with_port

  puts 'hash data: ' + data.inspect

  saveListData(params[:id], data, _class, foreign_key)

  url = {'url' => "http://#{host_with_port}/patients/#{params[:id]}#{route_fragment}"}.to_json
  Rack::Response.new(url)
end
```

Here is the logging when the helper is in the route file:

```
request body{"list_data":[{"id":8440,"value":"Removal of ear wax (procedure)"},{"id":9827,"value":"Foreign body in nose (disorder)"}]}
hash data: {"list_data"=>[{"id"=>8440, "value"=>"Removal of ear wax (procedure)"}, {"id"=>9827, "value"=>"Foreign body in nose (disorder)"}]}
```

And when I move it to the helpers file:

```
request body{"list_data":[{"id":8440,"value":"Removal of ear wax (procedure)"},{"id":9827,"value":"Foreign body in nose (disorder)"}]}
NoMethodError - undefined method `parse' for Sinatra::JSON:Module:
```

## Am I missing something really simple?

EDIT, got the debugger working. "data" after request.body.read in routes file:

```
"{&quot;list_data&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:8440,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Removal of ear wax (procedure)&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:9827,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Foreign body in nose (disorder)&quot;}]}"
```

in helpers file:

```
"{&quot;list_data&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:8440,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Removal of ear wax (procedure)&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:9827,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Foreign body in nose (disorder)&quot;}]}"
```

So the content looks identical to me. I can literally cut and paste this method between the two files, it works fine in the routes file, fails with undefined method parse in the helpers file. I'm guessing I've somehow defined that module improperly or have a dandling or missing character, but RubyMine is showing no errors, and the method does at least partially execute, so the method is getting sourced.

Complete helpers file:

```
module Sinatra
  module DynFormat
    CONTENT_TYPES={'xml' => 'text/xml','json' => 'application/json'}

    def dynamicFormat(data,format=params[:format])
      content_type CONTENT_TYPES[format], :charset => 'utf-8'
      case format
        when 'xml'
          data.to_xml
        when 'json'
          data.to_json
      end
    end
  end
  helpers DynFormat

  module RouteHelpers
    def processPutRequest(patient_id, request, _class, foreign_key, route_fragment)
      p = Patient.find(patient_id)
      data = request.body.read
      puts 'request body' + data
      data = JSON.parse(data)
      host_with_port = request.host_with_port

      puts 'hash data: ' + data.inspect

      saveListData(params[:id], data, _class, foreign_key)

      url = {'url' => "http://#{host_with_port}/patients/#{params[:id]}#{route_fragment}"}.to_json
      Rack::Response.new(url)
    end

    def saveListData(patient_id, list_data, _class, foreign_key)
      p = Patient.find(patient_id)

      _class = eval _class

      list_data = list_data['list_data']
      list_data.each do |x|
         _class.create(:patient_id => patient_id, foreign_key => x['id'] )
      end
    end


  end
  helpers RouteHelpers

end
```

Comment: do you add " require './helpers' " in app.rb ?

Comment: yes, and another helper in helpers.rb is working

Comment: Are you using anything from Sinatra contrib? In particular [`Sinatra::JSON`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/json.html), or requiring all extensions with `require 'sinatra/contrib/all'`?

Comment: funny you should ask that just now... I was evaluating expressions in both files, saw that JSON evaluated differently in the two files. When I saw your question, I looked at all of my requires and realized I was sourcing both json and sinatra/json.

Comment: I'm new at this, so I probably added these over time without realizing one was already present. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

When you put your method in the external file, you are putting into a module under the `Sinatra` namespace:

```
module Sinatra
  module DynFormat
    #...
  end

  module RouteHelpers
    def processPutRequest(patient_id, request, _class, foreign_key, route_fragment)
      # code that refers to JSON...
    end
  end
end
```

When your method calls `JSON.parse` it ends up finding the `Sinatra::JSON` module, not the top level `JSON` module that you intended, and so you get the error `` undefined method `parse' for Sinatra::JSON:Module ``.

When you include the method in a `helpers` block in your main file the method isn’t defined under the `Sinatra` module, so `JSON` refers to the correct top level module.

If you need to include `Sinatra::JSON`, you can explicitly refer to the top level module using `::`:

```
data = ::JSON.parse(data)
```

Also note that you don’t necessarily need to define your helper modules under `Sinatra` (though the docs do suggest you do). You can move them out of the `Sinata` module, and then use e.g. `Sinatra.helpers RouteHelpers` to register them as helpers.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, especially why the external file was handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

I was requiring both json and sinatra/json. No idea why the last one didn't win all the time, but removing sinatra/json resolved the issue. If something else breaks, I'll spend the time deciding between the two.